# Why is $u'(0)=0$ in this argument?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces

Let $I= (0, 1)$. Let $u \in L^2 (I)$ such that $u'' \in L^2 (I)$. Below is a proof (from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1825797/368425)) that $u' \in L^2 (I)$.

---

Let $v (x) := \int_0^x u'' (s) \, \mathrm d s$ for $x \in I$. By Hölder's inequality, $|v(x)| \le \| u'' \|_{L^2} \sqrt x$. Then $v \in L^2 (I)$. For $\varphi \in C^\infty_c (I)$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_I v \varphi' &= \int_I \left ( \int_0^x u'' (s) \, \mathrm d s \right )  \varphi' (x) \, \mathrm d x \\
&= \int_I \left ( \int_s^1 \varphi' (x)  \, \mathrm d x \right ) u'' (s)  \, \mathrm d s \quad\text{by Fubini's theorem}\\
&= -\int_I \varphi (s) u'' (s)  \, \mathrm d s \quad\text{by FTC}\\
&= -\int_I \varphi'' (s) u (s)  \, \mathrm d s,
\end{align*}
$$
which implies
$$
\int_I u \varphi' = -\int_I v \varphi \, \mathrm d s.
$$

It follows that $v = u'$.

---

**My question** It follows from the construction of $v$ that $v(0)=0$ (for *every* such $u$). This does not make sense for me.

> Could you elaborate on my confusion?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In the third line of your integration, you applied the FTC on the integral between $s$ and $1$. We should evaluate this as $\varphi(1) - \varphi(s)$, however this brings up a bigger question. It is my understanding that the corollary to the FTC requires our function to be defined on a closed interval, however the function $\varphi$ was only defined on the open interval $I$.

Comment: @Jensense the support of $\varphi$ is compact and contained in $I$, so we can extend it to the whole $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I had forgotten that tidbit; it seems to me that this still depends upon the extension at 1, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion comes from when you conclude: "which implies...". This is not true, what you can say is
$$
\int_I v\varphi' \, dx = -\int_I u\varphi''\, dx,\qquad \varphi\in C_c^\infty.
$$
Notice that if $v$ satisfies the above, then so does $v+C$ for any constant $C$. This is not true of your conclusion: Only one choice of constant $C$ should give an actual derivative of $u$!

Fix $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I)$. We want to show that for some $C\in \mathbb{R}$ (independent of $\varphi$ of course) we have
$$
\int_I (v-C)\varphi\, dx =-\int_I u\varphi'\, dx.
$$

Fix $\eta\in C_c^\infty(I)$ with $\int_I \eta=1$ and set $\phi:=\varphi-\varphi_I\eta$, which is in $C_c^\infty(I)$ and has zero average so that $\psi(x):=\int_0^x \phi(t)\, dt$ is also in $C_c^\infty(I)$ and so using $\psi$ as our test function we get
$$
\int_Iv(\varphi-\varphi_I\eta)\, dx = -\int_I u(\varphi'-\varphi_I\eta')\, dx.
$$
Rearranging terms we see
$$
\int_I \left(v-\int_I(v\eta+u\eta')\, dy\right)\varphi\, dx = -\int_I u\varphi'\, dx.
$$